# Probability that fourth number is greater than first number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

> We have a bag which contains $49$ numbers. We draw $6$ numbers randomly without replacement.
>
> What is the probability that the fourth number is greater that the first one?

**My approach:**

First we define the sample space by
$$\Omega:=\{(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_6)\mid 1\leq\omega_i\leq 49,~ \omega_i\neq\omega_j \text{ where } 1\leq i\neq j\leq 6\}$$
and
the two sets
$$A_1:=\{(\omega_1,\dots\omega_6)\mid \omega_1>\omega_4\}\text{ and } A_4:=\{(\omega_1,\dots\omega_6)\mid \omega_1<\omega_4\}.$$
We are looking for $\mathbb{P}(A_4)$.

As each outcome has the same probability we have $\mathbb{P}(A_4)=\frac{|A_4|}{|\Omega|}$, where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $A$. It is clear that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint and $\Omega=A_1\cup A_4$.

We define the function $f:A_1\to A_4$, where
\begin{align*}
&f(\omega)=b\implies f((\omega_1,\dots\omega_6))=\begin{cases}b_1=\omega_4\\b_2=\omega_2\\b_3=\omega_3\\ b_4=\omega_1\\b_5=\omega_5\\b_6=\omega_6.\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It is obvious that $f$ maps to $A_4$, is surjective and injective. So $f$ is a bijection and $|A_1|=|A_4|$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(A_4)=\frac{|A_4|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}|\Omega|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the probability that the first number is greater than the fourth one? There is a bijection between the two options, so they are equal and exhaust all possible outcomes. Most contexts it would not be necessary to express this in so much detail (I think unless this is explicitly an exercise in translation of a simple problem into formal concepts).

Comment: @MarkBennet, I wanted to practise the correct use of the formal concept because in the exam we have to argue formally.